# Why am I having an error in the substring?

Tags: java, android

May be the code is a mess but my knowledge of Java is not very good.

I have the following function and I'm having an error in the substring, but I cannot guess why.

```
private static void generateCode()
{       
    BigInteger basenumBig = BigInteger.valueOf(9007199254740989L);
    long basenum = basenumBig.longValue();

    StringBuilder index = new StringBuilder("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");

    long base = index.length();

    String out = new String();
    for (long t = (long) Math.floor(Math.log(basenum) / Math.log(base)); t >= 0; t--) {
        long bcp = (long) Math.pow(base, t);
        int a = (int) (Math.floor(basenum / bcp) % base);
        out = out + index.substring(a, 1);
        basenum = basenum - (a * bcp);
    }
    out = new StringBuilder(out).reverse().toString();

    System.out.println("CODE (" + out + ")");
}
```

The result should be "fE2XnNGpF"

Comment: index.substring(a, 1) looks suspicious; did you mean index.substring(a, a+1)?

Answer (score 2):

It seems you're using the `substring` function as (start index, length), which is unfortunately not how it works in Java's string class. From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)), the two arguments to the substring function are the start index (inclusive) and the end index (exclusive). So if you want a length 1 substring starting at `a`:

```
index.substring(a, a+1);
```

Specifically, your current code is probably throwing an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` because sometimes the beginIndex (*a*) is larger than endIndex (*1*).

Comment: I ported that code form PHP and there the substring is set like substr(a, 1) in which a is always a > 1. Which function do you recommend me to use instead of substring so the start point can be bigger than 1 but the end being 1? Thank you

Comment: I'm a bit confused by what you mean; it isn't possible for a substring to have its starting point after its ending point (unless you're wrapping around or something). That said, the output of "abcdef".substring(3, 4) in java is the same as substr("abcdef", 3, 1) in php.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `substring` in the wrong way, it takes input as `substring(start index, end index)`. So the code should be like

```
out = out + index.substring(1, a);
```